# Default taxonomy 'post_tag' added to CPT managing by custom role : nothing in the metabox

Tags: custom-post-types, metabox, taxonomy, tags, user-roles

I've created a Custom post type, which a custom role can manage : it has only the capabilities for managing this CPT.

When registering the CPT, I've set the argument : 'taxonomies' => array( 'post_tag' )
But when I go to the form of this CPT logged in as a user in the custom role, I can see the Metabox "Tags", but only the title header, there is nothing in the box.

I've not found any capability for giving it to the custom role....
How could this be fixed ?

Thx !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess your custom user role does not have the required capability to assign terms, which in case of the `post_tag` taxonomy would be `edit_post`.

So one thing to do would be giving it to your role—which is most likely not what you would like to do as this does not only affect assigning terms but also a number of other actions).

Another thing you could do is using the [`map_meta_cap`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/map_meta_cap) function. If you choose to take on this approach and you have any problems, just say so, and I will try to help you.